# Is a guest-operator QSO recorded in the host-station log too?

Tags: legal, logging, india

Just what the title reads.

An amateur may operate outside his own shack from another operator's station, or from a club-station etc.

As a matter of protocol, the guest operator is expected to identify the host-station at-least at the beginning, and end of the QSO.

Amateur Service regulations in **VU-land** mandate the active participants in a QSO maintain their own log.

Is it necessary that the host-station log the QSO of a guest operator? 
What about else-where on Earth?

Comment: Every club I've seen does this, as that is the nature of a club station, other operators using the one station. Like Phil mentioned though, logging isn't mandated everywhere. A bit more info would be good.

Comment: @PhilFrost Good point. I was labouring under the mistaken impression that logging is part of the ITU regs. Added reference to my local jurisdiction; it would be great to learn how it is elsewhere in the world too

Answer (score 3):

The question doesn't specify that the guest operator is a licensed amateur in the jursdiction in question and/or covered by a reciprocal operating agreement, otherwise we open up the 3rd party comminication bag of snakes.

Speaking only for the US rules:

There is no *requirement* that a guest operator logs be kept.  However, according to FCC §97.103(b): "The FCC will presume that the station licensee is also the control operator, unless documentation to the contrary is in the station records." So, you don't have to log individual contacts, but it might well be a *very good idea* to keep at least a record of who operated your station, with time and date and probably the frequencies.

Reference: FCC Part 97: http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/CFR-2000-title47-vol5/pdf/CFR-2000-title47-vol5-part97.pdf

EDIT:
The Canadian rules look quite similar (shocking, I know).  The relevant rules are located in their Radiocommunications Regulations: http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/regulations/SOR-96-484/page-11.html#h-44

Answer (score 2):

**In Sweden,** there is no requirement that *any* logs be kept; keeping a station log is purely voluntary, and I know that many don't, particularly for mobile or repeater QSOs.

The only really relevant example I can think of is when I was an operator at the [SK0TM](http://web.comhem.se/sk0tm/) station at the technical museum in Stockholm; the log book did not indicate the control operator, but other records did. SK0TM being the [Swedish Amateur Radio Association's](http://www.ssa.se/) promotion station it was probably a bit more formal than most club stations; to be allowed as a control operator, you not only needed a license of your own but also to sign a legal agreement, receive training in the museum's policies as well as specific station instructions, prove by showing your operator badge (matched against the list of planned control operator by day) to the cashier that you were authorized to take care for the day of the key to the station room, and so on.

I've operated club stations where I recall no formal records being kept as to who was the control operator at the time, though I do think most keep a thorough log. Even for club stations though, a station log is voluntary.

Answer (score 2):

Here in Serbia, logs of a station must be kept for two years.

In the case of a club radio station, each operator must sign the log for every use of the station; however the case of a guest using the station doesn't seem to be explicitly defined.

[The relevant document](http://www.ratel.org.rs/editor_files/File/Regulativa/Pravilnici/Pravilnik%20o%20radioamaterima,%20korigovan.pdf) says the following (translated by me):

> **III.3. Log of an amateur radio station**
>
> **Article 39**
>
> The data relating to amateur radio communications of any amateur radio
>   station shall be entered in the logbook of the amateur radio station.
>
> The log of an amateur radio station shall be kept in a manner that
>   provides a permanent record of written or electronic form.
>
> Mandatory data to be entered in the logbook of amateur radio stations
>   are:
>
> 1. the day, month and year of actual amateur radio communication;
> 2. start time of amateur radio communication, and in
>      case of longer transmissions, the start and end of the transmission;
> 3. The call sign which identified emission correspondent amateur station;
> 4. the name of the used amateur frequency band;
> 5. the type of emission;
> 6. the signature of the radio amateur (for club stations).
>
> Day and month are entered as a group of four Arabic numbers.
>
> The time is expressed as Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), and is
>   always entered as groups of four Arabic numerals marking the hours and
>   minutes (00 00).
>
> In addition to the information specified in
>   paragraph 3 of this article, the information about signal quality and
>   reception quality, the location of the amateur radio station whose
>   transmission is received, the name of the operator of the
>   correspondent station, the type and intensity of disturbance, etc. can
>   be logged.
>
> The log of an amateur radio station shall be kept for at least two years
>   from the date of last entry.